# Loop on Union process [ArcGis10/Python]

Tags: python, loops, union

I work on ArcGIS 10 and I'd like to realize multiple unions between layers. 
But that union task is a little bit particular. Indeed as the beginning of my code shows, I have seven layers (these layers have a specific classification).

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

workspace_2 = "V:/DONNEES/1_referentiels/mnt/1_france/1_dep_17/ign/litto3d/Litto3D_livraison_2011_10_24/traitements_lienss/tests/Workspace_chev/"
M0 = workspace_2 + "0.shp"
M1 = workspace_2 + "1.shp"
M2 = workspace_2 + "2.shp"
M3 = workspace_2 + "3.shp"
M4 = workspace_2 + "4.shp"
M5 = workspace_2 + "5.shp"
M6 = workspace_2 + "6.shp"
M7 = workspace_2 + "7.shp"
```

And my goal is to make an union between : M0 - M4, M1 - M5, M2 - M6 and so on. That is to say the union have to made **every four layers**. So I decided to make a loop but I must admit I'm completely lost. I tried that but it didn't work :

```
Union_1 = {"M0":M0, "M1":M1, "M2":M2, "M3":M3}
Union_2 = {"M4":M4, "M5":M5, "M6":M6, "M7":M7}

for i in Union_1:
    for j in Union_2:
        InFeatures = [Union_1[i], Union_2[j]]
        arcpy.Union_analysis (InFeatures, i + "_" + j + ".shp", "NO_FID", 0.0003, "")
        print "ok"
```

Could you help me to loop that union process ?

Comment: So the output desired in this case would be a single union_analysis of 4 consecutive segments (M0-M4 as a  single union_analysis call) is this correct?

Comment: Thank you very much NothingMore, I will test it tomorrow (indeed I just came back home !)

Comment: To stay readble, the output desired is at first the union of M0 and M4. Then an other union of M1 and M5, then M2 and M6 and so on. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

One way this loop could be done is the following

```
r = [m0, m1, m2, ..... , mN]
for n in range(0, len(r), 4):
   InFeatures = r[n:n+4]
   arcpy.Union_analysis (InFeatures, str(n) + "_" + str(n+4) + ".shp", "NO_FID", 0.0003, "")
```

This is if you are always looking to perform union_analysis on four sequential shape files.

Comment: Hello ! I just tried it and it failed. The error message says:  Traceback (most recent call last):
`File "V:\DONNEES\1_referentiels\mnt\1_france\1_dep_17\ign\litto3d\Litto3D_livraison_2011_10_24\traitements_lienss\tests\test.PY", line 23, in <module>
    arcpy.Union_analysis (InFeatures, str(n) + "_" + str(n+4) + ".shp", "NO_FID", 0.0003, "")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 483, in Union
    raise e` And then I have the ERROR 000210 : impossible to create the file 0_4.shp. Have you got an idea ?

Comment: ok it finally worked ! I just forgot to indicate the path of the folder in the "arcpy.union_analysis" line. For example one does write : `arcpy.Union_analysis (InFeatures, "C:\\julien_" + str(i) + "_" + str(j) + ".shp", "NO_FID", 0.0001, "")`. Thank you very much for your help !